# How to display truncated text in a clickable table on touch screen?

Tags: data-tables, text, touch-screen, tooltips

[image]In a table with clickable rows (a click on each row opens the dedicated page), the text could be truncated if it's too long. We thought to add a tooltip with the complete text on hover, but our app can be used on both desktop and tablet.

How might we display truncated text in a clickable table on a touch screen?

Comment: Can you share a minimal sketch or screenshot of your table? I'm worried I can't imagine your table correctly.

Comment: @Shahriar Here's a screenshot of the [table](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dHZFui1iF4ignUAVd7i4xad2bYVs8lRk/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide an icon on the row (or specific cell) that users can click to see the full text either in an expanded row or in a separate pop-up.